# Cannot execute dot in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, graphviz

Hi everyone I have this problem on python i have try to solve the problem put the problem is here please i posts the problem in our topic.

```
File "C:\Users\constantinos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\graphviz\files.py", line 188, in render
rendered = backend.render(self._engine, format, filepath, renderer, formatter)
File "C:\Users\constantinos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\graphviz\backend.py", line 183, in render
run(cmd, capture_output=True, check=True, quiet=quiet)
File "C:\Users\constantinos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\graphviz\backend.py", line 150, in run
raise ExecutableNotFound(cmd)
graphviz.backend.ExecutableNotFound: failed to execute ['dot', '-Tpdf', '-O', 'iris'], make sure the Graphviz executables are on your systems' PATH
```

Comment: as the error suggests, you must install Graphviz and add it your system PATH. Specific steps depend on your system, you can easily find the answers to these online

Answer (score 4):

You have to install `graphviz` for this to work, not just the Python package, but also the binary distribution.

See https://www.graphviz.org/

Then you have to put the path to dot in your PATH environment variable.

Comment: thank you for the answer put i have process this  . i Make something wrong,

Comment: You have graphviz installed? Then you didn't set PATH properly. It needs to point to the folder where dot.exe is.

Comment: Yes i try to install using treminal windows .Now i try to download with our page.if download this what are the next step ?